# Backup all namespaces in Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

i've a bit troubled with backup aerospike namespaces, sure i know how to do it, but i want to do backup use 1 command
Documentation says that Backup performs using this command 
asbackup --host localhost --namespace test --directory backup.2018
but in this command only 1 namespace name is allow, i've try to use globbin * or -all but this stuff isn't working.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Aerospike does not provide an option to backup all namespaces in one go. So, you need to write a script which will go through all the namespaces and backup.